# list index out of range in 3-gram

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

I am trying to make code for generation some 3-gram, but if I run the code below, it gives me error:

```
list index out of range
```

at the line in the function `third_word` on the line `next_word = word_list[x+2]`.

```
def third_word(key):
   third = {}
   next_word = word_list[x+2]

   if next_word not in third:
       third[next_word] = 1

   elif next_word in third:
       third[next_word] += 1      

   return third

x = 0
for word in word_list:
    key = (word_list[x], word_list[x+1])

    if key not in follow_ups:
        follow_ups[key] = third_word(key)

    x += 1
```

Comment: What is `word_list`?

Comment: `x` will run from `0` to `len(word_list)-1`.  If the last key isn't in `follow_ups`, then you will try to index with `len(word_list)+1` which will give an error.  Similarly for the second-to-last key, which will use `len(word_list)`, which is also out of bounds.  Also, `third` isn't doing anything since it's not global and always empty in `third_word`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every word in your word_list, you want to access element x+2. Suppose your word_list has n elements indexed from 0 to n-1, then you want to access the n+1th word when we are on the last iteration of the list, which is obviously out of bounds.

I suggest you generate the index with range instead, go with:

```
for x in range(len(word_list) - 2):
     ...
```

Comment: you probably mean `len(word_list)-2`